# JS: TypeError: this._init is not a function. (In 'this._init()', 'this._init' is undefined)

Tags: javascript, class, oop, typeerror

maybe you will find the problem. The console always says:

**TypeError: this._init is not a function. (In 'this._init()', 'this._init' is undefined)**

```
nodes = [];
for (var i = 0; i < 3; i++) {
    var newNode = new Node(i*100,0);
    nodes.push(newNode);
};

function Node(posX, posY, parent) {
    if (typeof parent === 'undefined') { parent = 0; }
    this.parent = parent;
    this.children = [];
    this.text = "Node";
    this.posX = posX;
    this.posY = posY;
    this._init();

    this._init = function() {
        alert("test");
    }
}
```

Comment: Why should it be a function? You're defining it after trying to call it. Function expressions are not hoisted.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to define the function before invoking it:

```
function Node(posX, posY, parent) {
    if (typeof parent === 'undefined') { parent = 0; }
    this.parent = parent;
    this.children = [];
    this.text = "Node";
    this.posX = posX;
    this.posY = posY;

    this._init = function() {
        alert("test");
    }

    this._init();   
}
```

http://jsfiddle.net/4wsLhd8y/

You may be confused by this if you have invoked functions before they were defined elsewhere. Under certain conditions, your function could be "hoisted"
to the top of your script. The following shows a completely legal invocation:

```
isItHoisted();

function isItHoisted() {
    console.log("Yes!");
}
```

http://adripofjavascript.com/blog/drips/variable-and-function-hoisting

As you are probably now aware, method functions on objects aren't hoisted, so you get the error you are seeing.

Comment: I have another script where it's working, even if the function is defined after the call!

Comment: @Hustensaft Added some more context.

Answer (score 0):

Looks like you are calling _init before you define it.

```
this._init = function() {
   alert('test');
}

this._init();
```

Comment: I have another script where it's working, even if the function is defined after the call!

Comment: I would not rely on that method. JS hoisting is a tricky thing to deal with, and will change in the next version by not being allowed at all for the most part. Functions are not typically hoisted.

Comment: Is it possible to define a init-Method afterwards? For example with `Node.prototype = {...}`?

Comment: You can overwrite the method, yes. So after the initial setup (as seen above in my example), you could then do another "this._init = function () { }"

I think any more on this and we'll need the use case for doing this in this manner. It is contrary to good coding standards.